# oracle sql time comparison

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this oracle table and the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE data( 
 fielda DATE DEFAULT sysdate, //sample data: 06/02/2021
  fieldb TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE DEFAULT current_timestamp //sample data:05/02/2021 11:44:04.000000000
);
```

I want to list all records in table data, where timea is not equal to timeb.

I wrote this query:

```
select * from  data where TO_DATE(timea, 'dd/mm/yyyy') != TO_DATE(timea, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ;
```

but i get error:
`ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string`

Do advise how to  list all records in table a, where timea is not equal to timeb.

Comment: What are the data types of the columns?

Comment: Please edit the question and show the table definition and exact sample format

Comment: updated question with sample data, field type

Comment: Your table name does not match what is in the query.  Where is mt_mdate, mt_ptime?  Please show a complete CREATE TABLE statement for the tables.

Comment: added the sql creation schema also

Answer (score 0):

oracle basic data types : date and timestamp are two different data types. the last one is more percise.
your to_date conversion seems very wired. to_date convert a string (text format) to a date.
according your table defination , fielda is a date type. why do the convert ? what is the parameter timea? to_date(timea,...) != to_date(timea,...)  whats your point ?
supporsed you are try to query some record which not match the specified date , the where clause should be like " where sometable.somefiled != to_date('specified_date_string_with_format','specified_format')"

Comment: fielda and fieldb both contain time.I want to list records where fielda and fieldb dont match

Comment: what your code show  abveriously isn't the original code. the parameter timea seems very wired.
if you want compare a date type with specified date value , the right value of the equal should be a date type value. or you do the convert  like "  fielda !=to_date('2021-02-09 10:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS) "